# How to save (upload) files to database after inserting records

Tags: sql-server

What I have seen in some sample use:

```
string strQuery = "insert into tblFiles(Name, ContentType, Data)" + 
                  " values (@Name, @ContentType, @Data)"
```

for saving files to the database.

Now if I have an existing table that has some rows and also some different filled columns, and after adding new columns (`Name, ContentType, Data`) to this existing table, I like to upload or save files.

What is the SQL statement I have to use to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The INSERT statement you have should work, provided that the data field is a `binary` field. However, always always, you're better off saving your files in the file system, with a link stored in the database.

Comment: Sometimes you are better storing files in the database, it really depends on the requirements and architecture of the code and solution e.g. load balancing could be in place

Comment: As well with the intro of FILESTREAM with SQL 2008 it is possible to have the file stored on the file system and SQL Server directly accesses it. This allows for your database backup to also include those filestream objects as well, keeping your data in sync.

Answer (score 0):

Here is roughly what you need to do:

1. Get file contents and turn it into a byte array (outside of SQL Server) in some server side code
2. Use the bytes array to insert the file into the database

Here is an example using ASP.Net MVC:

[ASP MVC 2 Uploading file to database (blob)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461638/asp-mvc-2-uploading-file-to-database-blob)

Comment: actually my record has been inserted to the table before just i like to fill some other fields of my record that related to upload file.what sql i have to use?